# WPF MahApps.Metro DropDownButton hide arrow

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Is it possible to hide 'arrow' on MahApps.Metro DropDownButton?

Right now it looks like this:

[image: my button]

And here's the code:

```
<controls1:DropDownButton
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"

    Orientation="Vertical"
    DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems }">
    <controls1:DropDownButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="controls1:DropDownButton">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource More}"></Image>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </controls1:DropDownButton.Style>
    <controls1:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}" />
        </Style>
    </controls1:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
</controls1:DropDownButton>
```

Is it possible to remove this 'arrow'?

I have tried to replace `Template` but this removed functionality of DropDown.

Comment: You probably have to use a custom template for the dropdown. See: http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/2/20/customizing-wpf-combo-box-style

Comment: I also think you are able to set the Image as the Icon Property of that control, so you don't need to set the Content Property.

Comment: My main concern is to remove this arrow from button

Answer (score 3):

you can set the ArrowVisibility attribute to collapsed

```
 <controls:DropDownButton Name="__BtExitApp"
                                         Orientation="Vertical"
                                         Content="Quit"                                                                           
                                 Grid.Column="2"
                                 x:FieldModifier="public"   
                                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="2,2,2,2"
                                 ArrowVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 >
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually the easiest way to change Thrid Party Styles is by using the original style (or template) and override it by yourself. You will probably need to do this as I don't see a property to hide the arrow in their source code.

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/DropDownButton.xaml

Maybe you would also be able to use a Attached Property and try to hide the element (as it's a [TemplatePart](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-part-names)).